# How can I fix "hcsshim:CreateComputeSystem" error in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Docker was running completely fine, until today, when I started getting this error when I try to build an image:

```
hcsshim:CreateComputeSystem winapi error #2147749890
```

This error appears as soon as it reaches a step that docker has to run something in the command line during the build.

I already tried to: reboot the computer, restart both docker and dockerd and removing all the containers and the unused images.

Any ideas what I should try to fix this error?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/navcontainerhelper/issues/811#issuecomment-571662531